# Understanding errno in C

Tags: c, errno

If I want to use a function that may return an error, for example thread_mutexattr_init(&myAttr), if this function returns an error it will automatically set errno with the number of the error or should I set errno to the return of this function?

For example what is right to do?

```
if((errno = pthread_mutexattr_init(&myAttr)) != 0){
    if(errno == EBUSY){
        perror("some error message because of EBUSY");
    }else{
        perror("another error message");
}
```

Or this:

```
if(pthread_mutexattr_init(&myAttr) < 0){
    if(errno == EBUSY){
        perror("some error message because of EBUSY");
    }else{
        perror("another error message");
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first version is correct out the two (the second is wrong actually - [`pthread_mutexattr_init()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_init.html) is required to return zero on success or a positive error number on failure; it is not defined to set `errno` so the value in `errno` is not necessarily relevant).

POSIX does not mandate pthreads functions to set `errno` (they may or may not set it -- there's no requirement). The returned value itself is the error number. If the returned value is `0` then success and if it's anything else you can assign it to `errno` to find the error (or use any other `int` variable to hold the value and then pass that to `strerror()`, for example).

Comment: Although the POSIX standard does not say that the pthread functions are prohibited from setting `errno`, the definition of [`errno`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/errno.html) says: _The value of `errno` shall be defined only after a call to a function for which it is explicitly stated to be set…_ and [`<errno.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/errno.h.html) says: _The `<errno.h>` header shall define the following macros which shall expand to integer constant expressions with type `int`, distinct positive values (except as noted below)…_

Comment: Since `pthread_mutexattr_init()` is not defined to set `errno`, it is not admissible (sensible) to check `errno` after the call.  And the function never returns a negative number: it returns 0 on success and a positive integer on failure.